# Prometheus node-exporter not returning metrics on Centos 6

Tags: prometheus, centos6, prometheus-node-exporter

Have tried with multiple versions of node exporter on a few Centos 6 VMs and I get the same thing.

Node exporter is running and when I `curl localhost:9100` I get this:

> Node Exporter
>
> ## Node
> Exporter
>
> [Metrics](/metrics)

When I `curl localhost:9100/metrics` it just hangs.

Any idea why it can't get the metrics?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of debugging, I discovered that it was hanging due to the filesystem collector.
Starting node_exporter with `--no-collector.filesystem` flag fixed the issue.